# Is it possible to have relational databases using Microsoft/SharePoint Lists?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, relational-database, sharepoint-list, linked-tables

I want to implement a system of linked tables using [Micorosft Lists](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/microsoft-lists) (formerly known as SharePoint Lists) to create a list of our suppliers, the services they provide to us, and the contact people inside those companies. I need to have three tabular data sets:

- services: specific attributes including the suppliers who can perform the process
- companies: general information like address, telephone numbers, processes they can conduct, and the contact people
- people: mobile number, email address, and the companies they work for ...

usually, the user will start with the first table to see what services fit their need better, then they go to the company table to see which one is preferred, and then to the last table to see who he/she should contact.

I created a Microsoft List to start with. On the top right corner when selecting the `All items > Edit current view`

[image]

In the `Web address of this view:` I see that the list is actually a `.aspx` file stored on our company SharePoint:

```
https://companyName.sharepoint.com/personal/userName/Lists/fileName/veiwName.aspx
```

Now my questions are:

- is there a way to edit that ASP.NET webpage directly?
- If that would be possible then how can I implement the above-linked tables?

I would appreciate it if you could be kind to advise me in the right direction, maybe linking to the relevant documentation and/or similar examples.

**P.S.1.** Following some links on the internet I installed SharePoint Designer, and I am able to open the `.aspx` file. though I have no clue where to go from here.

**P.S.2.** I also posted the question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/11f3o05/is_it_possible_to_have_relational_databases_using/) on Reddit, and there are already some nice responses over there.

Comment: Is your issue solved? Or are you still looking for help with this issue?

Comment: @CarlZhao I am still looking for a solution, though it seems Dataverse and PowerApps are in the right directions.